# Professional propagation of succulents by cuttings

Tags: succulents, propagation, cuttings

I live in a mediterranean climate. My zone is 11. Currently, I grow succulents which I can keep outside year-round.
I'm interested in professional books about what I'm growing:

Group 1: Haworthia, Gasteria, Aloe, Sansevieria

Group 2: Echeveria, Pachyphytum, sedum, Crassula, Kalanchoe

**My question** -- What professional books about propagation you know are good for advanced readers?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by 'professional' books about your plants - virtually any good gardening book on succulents with a section on propagation should be  useful, but by 'professional', do you mean on a scale large enough to start your  own business selling the plants, in other words, a trade or commercial operation?

Comment: In any field, not just horticulture, no commercial organization (if that's what you really mean by "professional") is going to help to produce a book that teaches its competitors how to be more competitive. You might find some *research* papers sponsored by government organizations, etc - some succulents are have economic value apart from being nice looking house and garden plants.

Comment: @bamboo Yes, about that quality of work, though I intend to use it to improve my techniques rather than attempting to beat competitors that use tissue culture. As an example, "bonsai succulents" by Philippe De-Vosjoli & Rudy Lime is a high-quality book and I am looking for something of that level but for the plants I grow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for off-site resources. Please see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/do-we-really-want-questions-asking-for-off-site-resources for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a book might be useful, but here's a workaround: why not just do a Web search for each of the plants on your list?

You can start here - I've found this person to be very knowledgeable about plants.

https://www.joyusgarden.com/propagate-sansevierias-snake-plants/

And here's a nice guide with pictures if you're interested in propagating Sansevieria from cuttings.

https://growandcare.com/sansevieria-trifasciata/

I did my searches with DuckDuckGo, but feel free to also use Google or one of the other search engines.

Bottom line is, there's a huge amount of information out there for free.  Look for a few different articles for each plant.  And if different articles give conflicting advice regarding a specific issue, you can always ask the friendly folks at StackExchange what they think.